# How to I change an existing website's git repo from azure to bitbucket

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a codebase on one of the Azure git repos (i.e. *.scm.azurewebsites.net:443) that I have migrated over to a repo on bitbucket.  How do I go about changing the configuration on my azure website to use this new repository?

I know how to do it with a new Azure website, I'm looking for instructions on modifying an existing repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the website's dashboard click on the link "Delete Git repository" (left side of the screen) and then (refresh the dashboard and) click on the link "Set up deployment from source control", there you can select your Bitbucket repository.

**Note:** Deleting the git repository will not affect the site (under wwwroot).

Comment: The fact that deleting the repository does not touch the website itself is very hard to find, but probably my first fear when seeing the button, so thanks Amit.

Comment: It's actually now called Disconnect from Bitbucket (or where ever your remote git is I imagine).